Round Function is not Working in the SharePoint list View Advanced Format
I am having a List View which aggregate the value. I am trying to display this value. The Round of Function is not working. But Floor is Working.
Below is the JSON formatting.
  {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "groupProps": {
    "headerFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "12px",
        "font-size": "16px",
        "font-weight": "400",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "outline": "0px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
      },
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "defaultClick"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "span",
              "style": {
                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px",
                "font-weight": "bold",
                "color": "Green"
              },
              "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-direction": "row",
                "justify-content": "center",
                "font-weight": "bold",
                "color": "blue"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "forEach": "totalValue in @aggregates",
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "txtContent": "= '(' + if([$totalValue.columnDisplayName] == 'UtilisedAmount', ' Utilised: ',if([$totalValue.columnDisplayName] == 'Balance_Amount',' Balance: ','Planed : ')) + ROUND(([$totalValue.value]/100000),2) + ' Lakhs )'"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


According to this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#operators
floor is a valid operator but round is not mentioned. You could try using ceiling

Thanks for your quick response. I can use ceiling. But the Value either be high (if ceiling) or low (if used floor). If I use split is there any way to get first and last index value and take only two digirs in last array value. This way I can do it. Still could not find a way to get first index value and last index value. Please help.

Can't you do something with substring instead of split? I don't think you can use the result of the split function to further alter the result. You are limited with the js you can execute
